# How to chain multiple .map() calls on previous items using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

In the example below I was wondering how you would go about preforming two operations on the same response from the .swichMap().

In the example I put the second .map in which is clearly wrong but sort of illiterates what I want to do. How would I go about calling two functions. Also when I break the fist map() out into a function like .map(response => {fn1; fn2;}); typescript throws an error?

```
@Effect()
    getUserCourse$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(userCourse.ActionTypes.LOAD_USER_COURSE)
        .map<string>(action => action.payload)
        .switchMap(userCourseId => this.userCourseApi.getUserCourse(userCourseId))
        .map(response => new userCourse.LoadUserCourseSuccessAction(response.data));
        .map(response => new course.LoadCourseSuccessAction(response.course));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I'm assuming that both functions `userCourse.LoadUserCourseSuccessAction` and `course.LoadCourseSuccessAction` do return Observables. If not you can always create one with `Rx.Observable.of` or `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` in case of for example an AJAX call.

If I understand you correctly you want to do independent things with the response, but do them in parallel and merge the results back in the stream. Have a look at the following code that shows how this can be archived.

```
Rx.Observable.of(
  {data: 'Some data', course: 'course1'},
  {data: 'Some more data', course: 'course2'}
).mergeMap((obj) => {
  // These two streams are examples for async streams that require
  // some time to complete. They can be replaced by an async AJAX 
  // call to the backend.
  const data$ = Rx.Observable.timer(1000).map(() => obj.data);
  const course$ = Rx.Observable.timer(2000).map(() => obj.course);

  // This Observable emits a value as soon as both other Observables
  // have their value which is in this example after 2 seconds.
  return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(data$, course$, (data, course) => {
    // Combine the data and add an additinal `merged` property for
    // demo purposes.
    return { data, course, merged: true };
  });
})
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[Runnable demo](https://jsbin.com/haxuvi/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks, this looks really good and was the sort of solution I was after. I like the idea running them in parallel and merging them back into the stream. I knew there would be a cool rxjs way of doing this.